# allow html 5 tags in tinymce editor for wordpress, when switching to visual tab in the editor and back

Tags: html, wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am simply trying to retain my `<u>` tags and `<b>` tags, in wp admin post editor.
 However when switching back and forth from the visual view to the text/html view they are being changed to `<span style="text-decoration: underline;"></span>`this is annoying and spans in my case would be problematic.

what is the best way to go about this, I have tried some plugins which aren't of help and adding and extending valid elements ... but have not succeeded as of yet!

It would be of great help if some of you geniuses could point me in the right direction.

Also a different question I have;

Is there a simple way to add a style button to the text editor that will change the direction of the form in the text view of the editor from ltr and rtl, 
I have done this easily via changing the css in the developer tools or firebug! but am asking for something built in!

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to disable the [`inline_styles`](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3ainline_styles) option (which is turned on by default in the version of TinyMCE that's included with Wordpress):

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', function ( $options )
{
    $options['inline_styles'] = false;

    return $options;
});
```

Although this works, I'd strongly advise against it. [This use of the `u` element has been deprecated in HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/u-element/), and is considered non-semantic in this context.

If you can explain why you're trying to do this, maybe we can come up with a better solution.

**P.S.** There's a great discussion about this [over at the TinyMCE forums](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=12291).

Comment: I would deem it semantic, if it isn't I could use b tags instead, but spans will cause trouble as I have functions that count the p text and not span text, also your snippet if added to functions.php causes a fatal error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! so where does it belong?

Comment: @webestdesigns - If you're using PHP under 5.3, you have to use a named function.

Comment: oops, thanks seems to be working fine now, but what drawbacks are there to consider for disabling this?

Comment: @webestdesigns - Other than allowing the creation of non-semantic markup...? Nothing I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to all this and I couldn't figure out how to do this so, here is the code. Pulled it from the core class-wp-editor.php file. Here it is:

```
function my_tiny_mce_tweaks( $first_init ) {
  $first_init['formats'] = '{' .
      'alignleft: [' .
          '{selector: "p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li", styles: {textAlign:"left"}},' .
          '{selector: "img,table,dl.wp-caption", classes: "alignleft"}' .
      '],' .
      'aligncenter: [' .
          '{selector: "p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li", styles: {textAlign:"center"}},' .
          '{selector: "img,table,dl.wp-caption", classes: "aligncenter"}' .
      '],' .
      'alignright: [' .
          '{selector: "p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li", styles: {textAlign:"right"}},' .
          '{selector: "img,table,dl.wp-caption", classes: "alignright"}' .
      '],' .
      'strikethrough: {inline: "del"},' .
      'underline: {inline: "u"}' .
  '}';

  return $first_init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_tiny_mce_tweaks');
```

PLEASE NOTE: It only changes the behavior of underline button, if you want bold, italic as `b` and `i` tags, add @Thariama's comment to the code.

Answer (score -1):

You may simple init your editor with the following

```
    // Override internal formats  
    formats: {
        bold : {inline : 'b' },  
        italic : {inline : 'i' },
        underline : {inline : 'u'}
    },
```

Tinymce will then treat bold, italic underline as b,u and i-tags.

Comment: in what function or filter do I add this?

Comment: this needs to be put in the tinymce init function where all configuration params are listed